# Creating SQL Server login via script using variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a SQL Server login following the creation of a database through script.
The login is local to the host PC and this script will be run on multiple hosts.

What I want to do is the following:

```
USING MyDatabase
CREATE MyUser FOR LOGIN USER <computer name>/MyUser
```

What I don't know how to do is incorporate the computer name (ex. Location0001) into this statement.

The login does exist on each machine AND is already listed on the SQL Server as it has access to other databases there.

If it's relevant, the script should be able to run on SQL Server 2008.

The login would look like this for each machine:

```
Location0001\MyUser
Location0002\MyUser
Location0999\MyUser
```

Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

***Edit: My final solution based on the accepted answer is as follows:***

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(200)
SET @cmd = N'CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [' + HOST_NAME() + '\MyUser]'
EXEC (@cmd)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the @@servername property to get the name of the machine: `select @@servername`

```
declare @cmd varchar(200), @username varchar(50)

set @username = 'testuser'
set @cmd = ' 
   USE MyDatabase
   CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN '+@@servername+'\'+@username 
PRINT @cmd
EXEC (@cmd)
```

Comment: I didn't think of using inline SQL.  Thank you, I had to made some syntax changes but the concept did work.

Comment: Consider using sp_executesql as opposed to EXEC(UTE).  It allows for parameterized queries which eliminates the possibility of SQL Injection as well as utilizes plan reuse from the plan cache.

Comment: This suggestion will only work for default instance. For named instances, `@@servername` will return 'MACHINE\INSTANCE', so CREATE USER will fail. You need either `HOST_NAME()` like OP suggested, or `ServerProperty('MachineName')`, depending on what you're trying to achieve. I know this has been answered - I am writing for those who get here from web searches.

Comment: user596075: the whole reason for constructing this is that the CREATE USER statement can't be parametrized.

Comment: sp_executesql does not work for this example. But yes, use sp_executesql for cases where actual parameters are passed.